# ASP.NET Show UpdateProgress instead of a control that's being updated

Tags: asp.net, multiview, updateprogress

I think everything I wanted to ask is in the title. I have a MultiView control and I want every time I change the view, the UpdateProgress control to show up in the place where the last view used to be (meaning I want to hide the most recently used view), while updating the information.